# xdotool Error: Can't open display: (null)

Tags: linux, macos, unix, zshrc, xdotool

"xdotool key" gives me the following error :

```
Error: Can't open display: (null)
Failed creating new xdo instance
```

I downloaded:

```
  brew cask install xquartz
  brew install xdotool
```

I added to zshrc file and saved with "source ~/.zshrc":

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

I tried exporting display but none seems to work.

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && xdotool key 'a'
```

*Im using mac

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: `I downloaded:

  brew` You tagged linux. Are you using linux or macos?

Comment: @KamilCuk macos